# How to use :host-context selector in an ngClass condition?

Tags: css, angular, ng-class

I want to set a class `active` on a div (part of a component) if a variable is true (`workspace.active` here) AND an ancestor element has class `.home`.
Something like:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'active': workspace.active && ':host-context(.home)', }">
```

Can I use somehow this pseudo selector `:host-context` in such an conditional expression for ngClass ?

Details:

I want to use same component in two use cases. Only some css properties should be different on the two cases. So I want to customize a css class set on a div on my component based on decision: "there is an ancestor `home` in the dom tree or not" - this should differentiate the two use cases.

I could do things like this in css:

```
:host-context(.home) .active {
  background-color: #405976;
}
```

but then all selector combinations containing `.active` class should be combined also with `:host-context` and I I don't want to grow the complexity in css as it is already complex.
I would prefer to just set the class `.active` based on the condition. In css file !, not in code. (This is why `:host-context` exists in the end.)

Comment: You can't and actually you shouldn't. You should not make any decisions in your code based on the HTML content. @Input() some variable in your component and make decision about 'active' class based on that. This is all I can guess since you've not provided any code.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. I implemented it and it works nice. Thank you. It is cleaner, I agree. 
Stil.... my first impression is that this way it will end up in adding extra complexity to the code instead of css. If for every such tiny decisions I would add an @Input (and sometimes some logic also) my component will be polluted with "too many features".
I would prefer letting css live it's own life as much as possible, without interfering with component code. :host-context is for such situations. You can use it in plain css but don't know how inside a ngClass expression in  css file.

Comment: You can always split it out into separate directive that will manage some css for you thus cleaning 'main' component from this concern.

Comment: can you formulate a response to accept it  ?
Thanks

Comment: Sure, I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular you should not make any logical decisions in the code based on the html content properties such as classes or attributes, but vice versa - you should render classes and attributes in html based on data bindings. That's the main idea of angular - rendering view based on data bindings. Component's code should not really care too much about view structure.

So, in this case if your class should be based on some external information you need to @Import() that data through data bindings into your component and then use component properties in the ngClass directive. Yes, it moves logic into the component instead of html/css, but that's where it's supposed to be anyway: in the model/controller code, not in the view markup. Also, this way it will be much more convenient to test such a component.